# An integral related to $\Gamma(\tfrac14)^2$

Tags: gamma-function, elliptic-integrals

I converted $\Gamma(\tfrac14)^2=16\Gamma(\tfrac54)^2$ to a double integral by definition of Gamma function. By using polar coordinates I eliminated one integral and found $12\sqrt{\pi}$ times the integral
$$\int_0^{\tfrac\pi 2}\frac{(\sin\theta\cos\theta)^{\tfrac14}}{(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)^{\tfrac52}}d\theta\tag1$$
I couldn't proceed further to show that $(1)$ is equal to $\frac13K(\tfrac1{\sqrt2})$ where $K(k)$ is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind.

Can anybody proceed further?

Comment: Please define $K(x)$ (it's the complex extension of the hyperfactorial, right?)

Comment: No. @calculatormathematical it is a complete elliptic integral. Does hyperfactorial use same letter?

Comment: The extension is called $K$-function: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/K-Function.html

Comment: You wrote $1/\sqrt{2}$, so this is the usual version of $K$, not the Mathematica version of $K$, where it would be $1/2$.

Comment: @Gedgar Yes usual version.

Answer (score 1):

The integral in question:
$$I=\frac{2^{3/4}}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin{(2x)}^{1/4}}{(\cos{x}+\sin{x})^{5/2}}dx \\\overset{x=x/2}=\frac{2^{3/4}}{4}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin{(x)}^{1/4}}{(\cos({x/2})+\sin({x/2}))^{5/2}}dx \\ \overset{x=2\arctan{t}}=
\frac{1}{12}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{t^{3/4}\sqrt{1+t}}.\tag{1}$$
In the other hand:
$$K(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})=\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+\cos^2{x}}}\\\overset{x=2\arctan{t}}=2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}\\\overset{t=t^{1/4}}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{t^{3/4}\sqrt{1+t}}\\\overset{t=\frac{1}{t}}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{t^{3/4}\sqrt{1+t}}\tag{2}.$$
Then with $(1)$ and making the sum of last two equalities in $(2)$ we have:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{t^{3/4}\sqrt{1+t}}=4K(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})=12I \implies I=\frac{1}{3}K(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}).\tag{3}$$

**Remarks**

- In the first step we have used: $$\sin({2x})=2\sin{x}\cos{x}\tag{a}$$.
- To get the integrals in $t$ we have used:
  $$\cos({\arctan{t}})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\tag{b},$$
  and
  $$\sin({\arctan{t}})=\frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\tag{c}.$$
  With $(a)$, $(b)$ and $(c)$ then:
  $$\sin({2\arctan{t}})=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\tag{d},$$
  and
  $$\cos({2\arctan{t}})=\frac{2}{1+t^2}-1\tag{e}.$$

Comment: Nice. +1. But I found $\frac{t^{\tfrac14}}{(t+1)^{\tfrac52}}$ in the integrand.

Comment: @BobDobbs don`t understand but: $t^{1/4-1}=\frac{1}{t^{3/4}}$ what's the issue?

Comment: Can you write a few more steps after $x=2\arctan t$ substitution, to show how $x$ integral becomes $t$ integral in detail?

Comment: ok @BobDobbs but you will see that are trivial details

Comment: I've updated it @BobDobbs

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. @User